# how to display the list view through onclick listener according to each user id

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i want to display the list view once i clicked on each user id that implement on list view. Once I clicked on the user id, the apps immediately stop.Anyone has any idea to solve the problem

here is my first list view java

```
public void search() {
    String str1 = editText.getText().toString();
    // Find ListView to populate
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view1);
    //LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> labels = loginDataBaseAdapter.searchData(str1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_list,R.id.tvsid, labels);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle passdata = new Bundle();
            Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            String studId = listCursor.getString(listCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID"));
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // Integer.toString(nameId), 500).show();
            passdata.putString("keyid", studId);
            Intent passIntent = new Intent(LecturerSearch.this,
                    LecturerResult.class);
            passIntent.putExtras(passdata);
            startActivity(passIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

and this is the second list view java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecturer_result);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.attendance_row);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    Bundle showData = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowId = showData.getString("keyid");
    loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter.getInformation(db, rowId);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{

            String location, date;
            location=cursor.getString(0);
            date=cursor.getString(1);
            DataAttendance dataAttendance =new DataAttendance(location,date);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataAttendance);

        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }


}
```

this is the function in first list view

```
 public ArrayList<String> searchData(String subject) {

    ArrayList<String> view = new ArrayList<String>();
    //String [] columns = {"ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID"};
    String selectQuery = "SELECT ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE SUBJECT=\""+ subject+ "\" GROUP BY ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID" ;

    try {
        //Cursor mCursor = db.query("ATTENDANCE",columns,"SUBJECT ='"+subject+"'",null,null,null,null);
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {
                view.add(mCursor.getString(0));
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            mCursor.close();
            return view;
        }
        return view;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return view;
}



this is the function of second listview

 public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db, String id){
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] projections = {"LOCATION","DATE"};
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query("ATTENDANCE",projections,"ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID ='"+id+"'",null,null,null,null,null);
    /*cursor = db.query("SELECT ATTENDANCE.LOCATION,ATTENDANCE.DATE," +
            "ATTENDANCE.SUBJECT,STUDENT.ID FROM STUDENT JOIN ATTENDANCE ON STUDENT.ID=ATTENDANCE.STUDENT_ID",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);*/

    return cursor;
}
```

This is the logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.azharwa.studentattendance, PID: 2209
              java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor
                  at com.example.azharwa.studentattendance.LecturerSearch$2.onItemClick(LecturerSearch.java:69)
                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3845)
                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3617)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
                  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zy
```

Comment: please post error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to
>   `android.database.Cursor`

You are getting `ClassCastException`. To resolve this error update `onItemClick()` method as below:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Student Id 
        String studId = labels.get(position);

        Intent passIntent = new Intent(LecturerSearch.this, LecturerResult.class);
        passIntent.putExtra("keyid", studId);
        startActivity(passIntent);
    }
});
```

**FYI,** as you are storing student `ids` to `labels` array and passed it to `adapter` to populate on `listview`. So, you can get `clicked` item's `position` from `onItemClick()` method and using this `position` easily you can get student `id` from `labels` array.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you, it realy works. But do you have any idea how to make it the listview based on particular subject and student id. The search function is to search the subject

Comment: If my answer seems useful then please mark it as right answer. "But do you have any idea how to make it the listview based on particular subject and student id"? Can you please describe what you want actualy?

Comment: How to mark it as right answer? I want to search the subject at the first, and then display the list the student id who had taken the subject. And when you click on the particular student id, there will be the list view of location and date. The list view of location and date are according to the particular student id that had taken the search sbject

Comment: as per your question, your second activity and method getInformation() seems ok. What kind of problem are you facing now?